# multiple chain of when() then() - defered object

Tags: javascript, jquery, deferred

I want to do a chain of $.when().then($when().then(...)) in jquery. I'm not used to the defered functions, first time using them.

I changed my code a bit my code to represent this situation:

```
function setenum(e)
{
    return $.ajax({
        url: SetPathUrl1(),
        type: 'GET',
        data: { isNew: e.isNew() },
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data, status, xhr) {
            /*My stuff*/
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            /*My stuff*/
        }
    });
}

function setdropdown1(e)
{
    return $.ajax({
            url: SetPathUrl2(),
            type: 'GET',
            data: { isNew: e.isNew() },
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                /*Fill my first ddl based on enum*/
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                /*My stuff*/
            }
        });
}

function setdropdown2(e)
{
    return $.ajax({
            url: SetPathUrl3(),
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                /*Fill my second ddl based on enum*/
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                /*My stuff*/
            }
        });
}

function DoOtherStuff(e)
{
    /**/
}

function MainNotWorking(ImportantModel)
{
    $.when(setenum(ImportantModel))
    .then(
        $.when(setdropdown1(ImportantModel),setdropdown2(ImportantModel))
        .then(
            function () {
                DoOtherStuff(e);
            }
        )
        );
}

function MainWorking(ImportantModel)
{

    $.when(setenum(ImportantModel),setdropdown1(ImportantModel),setdropdown2(ImportantModel))
    .then(
        function () {
            DoOtherStuff(e);
        }
    );

}
```

MainNotWorking : the order is not respected at all, set `setdropdown1` and `setdropdown2` are called sometimes before the `setenum`.

MainWorking:
When I have only one level of when, then the function `DoOtherStuff` is called before all other functions, but it's only one level. I want to do multiple chain `setenum` before `setdropdown1` and `setdropdown2` and then finally `DoOtherStuff`.

Comment: "`DoOtherStuff` is never called before all other functions are done", wasn't that the point of using Deferreds, to not call it until the other functions are done, or did you really mean that it's "never" called.

Comment: removed the `never` :P

Comment: Try it like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/qT6JZ/1/**

Comment: Thanks man, working great! You can make it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$.when().done(callback)`

```
function MainNotWorking(ImportantModel) {
    $.when(
        setenum(ImportantModel)
    ).done(function() {
        $.when(
            setdropdown1(ImportantModel), 
            setdropdown2(ImportantModel)
        ).done(DoOtherStuff);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you should pass a function reference to `then`:

```
.then(function() { ... })
```

What you are passing is executed immediately, instead of when the first function is finished.

That alone would be enough, but if you wanted to "flatten" out the chaining, you could do something like this:

```
$.when(
    setenum(ImportantModel)
).then(function() {
    return $.when(
        setdropdown1(ImportantModel),
        setdropdown2(ImportantModel)
    )
}).then(function() {
   DoOtherStuff(); 
});
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/44e5Y/